# Why I can't send SIGRTMAX-9 signal with kill command?

Tags: process, kill, signals

I have a bash script running in the background and wanted to send the **SIGRTMAX-9** signal to it.

### SIGRTMAX-* case

Why `kill` command doesn't recognize the **SIGRTMAX-9** signal?

```bsh
╭─ /tmp/tmp.KHFbrCQhOB                                                        
╰─ kill -SIGRTMAX-9 $(pgrep bash)
kill: unknown signal: SIGRTMAX-9
kill: type kill -l for a list of signals
```

If I run the kill command with `sudo`:

```bsh
╭─ /tmp/tmp.KHFbrCQhOB                                                        
╰─ sudo kill -SIGRTMAX-9 $(pgrep bash)
kill: invalid argument S

Usage:
 kill [options] <pid> [...]
 
 ...

 For more details see kill(1).
```

### SIGRTMIN+* case

If I send the **SIGRTMIN+3** it only works with `sudo`:

```bsh
╭─ /tmp/tmp.KHFbrCQhOB                                                 
╰─ kill -SIGRTMIN+3 $(pgrep bash)     
kill: unknown signal: SIGRTMIN+3
kill: type kill -l for a list of signals
```

```bsh
╭─ /tmp/tmp.KHFbrCQhOB                                                        
╰─ sudo kill -SIGRTMIN+3 $(pgrep bash)

╭─ /tmp/tmp.KHFbrCQhOB                                                        
╰─ echo $?                            
0
```

Comment: `man kill` is your friend. It will tell you how (and what) your version of `kill` supports. As for "why does it not support SIG<xyz>?", you will have to ask the author of your `kill` command, and ask them why--or ask them to include it in the next release.

Comment: @C.M. yeah, I read it before asking, thankfully I found the "error", it was a simple mistake, will be posting it as an answer soon, thank you!

Comment: I am not certain which `kill` man page you have, but mine has the warning: `NOTES  Your shell (command line interpreter) may have a built-in kill command.  You may need to run the command described here as /bin/kill to solve the conflict.` making it clear. ;-) In either case, you can always use the numeric value instead of the symbolic name. Which is why I pointed you at the man page.

Comment: I just checked it again, and you're totally right!, I must have skipped the NOTES section, fool of me, thank you! d:-D

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, simple as typing `which kill` it printed out `kill: shell built-in command`; the thing is that I was inside a **zsh session**, and it has a built-in `kill` command, I fixed it calling `/bin/kill -SIGRTMAX-9 $(pgrep bash)` instead of just `kill -SIGRTMAX-9 $(pgrep bash)`.